# delete URLs of all terms for a specific taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: 7, path-aliases

Using [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module,  I know we have a **Delete aliases** tab to delete URLs in bulk but what if we need to delete URLs of all terms for specific vocabulary?

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Might this issue be helpful https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto/issues/870404

Comment: you probably need a custom module to do that ... how about updating all aliases of specific vocabulary ? would that help in your end task ?

Comment: The question is merely, what do you like to achieve with removing the URL aliases? Do you want to "hide" them/make them inaccessible, or do you just want to have the generic URLs of Drupal to be used for this vocabulary?

Comment: @MarioSteinitz I'd have these as generic URLs of Drupal.

Comment: @GiorgosK, good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **delete** the aliases you will need a custom module or perhaps a custom VBO action based on the `update taxonomy term alias` action.  Here is a quick and dirty version of a custom module

**aliases_delete.info**

```
name = delete aliases
description = will delete vocabulary aliases for specific vocabulary 
package = aliases_delete
version = 1
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = pathauto
```

**aliases_delete.module**

```
<?php

function aliases_delete_menu() {
  $items['aliases_delete/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'aliases_delete_delete_vocabulary',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'taxonomy_term_edit_access',
    'access arguments' => array(2),
  );
  return $items;
}

function aliases_delete_delete_vocabulary($vocabulary_name){
  $vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($vocabulary_name);
  $terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', FALSE, array('vid' => $vocab->vid));
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    pathauto_entity_path_delete_all('taxonomy_term', $term, "taxonomy/term/{$term->tid}");
  }  
  return 'Deleted aliases of all terms in ' . $vocabulary_name;
}
```

If you enable and install this module you can visit as admin `aliases_delete/tags` to delete all aliases of terms in vocabulary **tags**

To **update** the path aliases of specific taxonomy terms (instead of **deleting**) you can use [VBO - views_bulk_operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)

- install and enable the module
- create a view of taxonomy terms and use appropriate filters for vocabulary
- add field "view bulk operations" and save your view
- go to your view and select all terms that will be updated (VBO can select multiple pages of results)
- choose the `update taxonomy term alias` action and press `execute`
- all terms should be updated according to the new pathauto rules

Comment: if I delete the both patterns for the specific vocabulary and the default pattern under the taxonomy patterns, then should this VBO *update taxonomy term alias* work? In my case it doesn't.

Comment: Aparently when the pattern is empty or it has default path `taxonomy/term/[term:tid]` the action does not change/update the ALIAS ... what are you looking to achieve ? ... put a specific pattern and it will work

Comment: `taxonomy/term/[term:tid]` is a core pattern while I was talking about the *admin/config/search/path/patterns* like in the [image](https://snag.gy/9aFsdJ.jpg).  When I empty these patterns and update as you answered it doesn't update.

My ideal achievement is to delete aliases that created by [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.

Comment: updated my answer